# How can I make a full-screen table in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am working on a program for Android, and I want to make a 3x7 (3 columns, 7 rows) table, where each cell holds a button.

I have tried using tableLayout, but every time the width of the tables are always too short or too long, meaning that there is either blank space or the buttons go off of the page.  I am not having a problem with the height, just the width.

This problem could also be solved easily with a layout like GridLayout from java.  Is there an equivalent to that in Android?

any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use linear layouts with weights.

Try this out, I think that does it, though it might take a little work, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width:"fill_parent" android:layout_height:"fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width:"fill_parent" android:layout_height:"fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout>    
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="ButtonText"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe set android:layout_width on you button in fix size  "185dp"